# Selecting time based on the max value of different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing traffic analysis and I have an aggregated view of average travel times with traffic. What I am attempting to do is select the time associated with the max average travel time for the given time periods.

Here is the code and results I am looking for, without time:

```
SELECT dt.datekey, dt.peak_hours, dt.weekday_name, 
ROUND(MAX(avg_t_dur_traffic)/60,2) MaxATT
FROM cat.Analytics_AvgTimes att
INNER JOIN cat.Dim_Date dt on att.DateKey = dt.DateKey and att.timekey = dt.timekey
WHERE dt.DateKey = '20170523' AND dt.peak_hours <> 'off_peak'
GROUP BY dt.DateKey, dt.Peak_Hours, dt.Weekday_Name

datekey     peak_hours    weekday_name  MaxATT
2017-05-23  AM_Peak       Tuesday       28.93
2017-05-23  Midday_Peak   Tuesday       14.05
2017-05-23  PM_Peak       Tuesday       29.95
```

*Edit: I'm not looking specifically for these three MaxATT times, I'm only looking for help on how to query the information...*

I see the Max Average Trip Time (MaxATT) during AM peak hours on Tuesday approx. 29 minutes. When I add in time is where I am having a hard time. I get the following results:

*Please note that I have removed a few rows from the results to save on space*

```
SELECT dt.datekey, dt.TimeKey, dt.peak_hours, dt.weekday_name, 
ROUND(MAX(avg_t_dur_traffic)/60,2) MaxATT
FROM cat.Analytics_AvgTimes att
INNER JOIN cat.Dim_Date dt on att.DateKey = dt.DateKey and att.timekey = dt.timekey
WHERE dt.DateKey = '20170523' and dt.peak_hours <> 'off_peak'
GROUP BY dt.DateKey, dt.Peak_Hours, dt.Weekday_Name, dt.TimeKey

datekey     TimeKey     peak_hours  weekday_name    MaxATT
2017-05-23  05:15:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         10.43
2017-05-23  05:30:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         10.45
2017-05-23  07:15:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         12.53
2017-05-23  07:30:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         18.27
2017-05-23  07:45:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         22.85
2017-05-23  08:00:00    AM_Peak     Tuesday         28.93
```

We can see the time associated with MaxATT = 28.93 is 08:00 during the AM peak. But all I want to select is each distinct time during each peak, ***so what I am looking for is***

```
datekey     TimeKey     peak_hours    weekday_name  MaxATT
2017-05-23  08:00:00    AM_Peak       Tuesday       28.93
2017-05-23  13:45:00    Midday_Peak   Tuesday       14.05
2017-05-23  17:30:00    PM_Peak       Tuesday       29.95
```

Here is an attempt at using RANK(), but I failed miserably as MaxATT does not match the correct value, and it pulls more records than just RANK() = 1

```
SELECT id, datekey, peak_hours, weekday_name, MaxAtt
FROM(
        SELECT id, dt.DateKey, dt.Peak_Hours, dt.Weekday_Name, 
        ROUND(MAX(avg_t_dur_traffic)/60,2) MaxAtt,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY MAX(avg_t_dur_traffic) DESC) AS 
        [rank]
        FROM cat.Analytics_AvgTimes att
        INNER JOIN cat.Dim_Date dt ON att.datekey = dt.DateKey AND att.TimeKey = dt.TimeKey
        GROUP BY id, dt.DateKey, dt.Peak_Hours, dt.Weekday_Name
     ) mt
WHERE mt.[rank] = 1 AND DateKey = '20170523' AND peak_hours <> 'off_peak'
GROUP BY id, datekey, peak_hours, weekday_name, MaxAtt
```

Thank you for the help and if you need further clarification please feel free to ask!

[*Edit: Sample data as requested*](https://pastebin.com/UHwa9yDu)

Comment: Can you please provide few sample data and desired resulut, it is hard without sample data and exact result

Comment: I added sample data.

Comment: What result you expect from the sample data? Your expected result not same with your sample data.

Comment: @ColourDalnet my apologies for the confusion. The explicit values in the sample data does not match what is posted in the question. I'm looking for help with formatting and being able to pull the values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the maxatt rows needed and they join that to the original table.

```
select a.* 
from cat.Analytics_AvgTimes a
Inner JOIN (
          select datekey, peak_hours, weekday_name, max(maxatt) as maxatt
          from cat.Analytics_AvgTimes
          group by datekey, peak_hours, weekday_name) b
ON a.datekey = b.datekey and a.peak_hours = b.peak_hours and 
   a.weekday_name = b.weekday_name and a.maxatt = b.maxatt
```

fiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcacb9/1/0

edit after reviewing data:

```
select one.*
from (select a.*, b.Avg_T_Dur_Traffic as max
      from dim_date a, Analytics_AvgTimes b
      where a.datekeyid = b.id) one
INNER JOIN (
      select a.*, max(b.Avg_T_Dur_Traffic) as max
      from dim_date a, Analytics_AvgTimes b
      where a.datekeyid = b.id
      group by datekey, monthid, weekid, dayid, peakhoursid) two
      ON one.datekey = two.datekey and one.monthid = two.monthid and
         one.weekid = two.weekid and one.dayid = two.dayid and one.max = two.max
```

fiddle with provided data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7889a/9

Comment: Thank you for your help. I attempted to do something similar using your example, but nothing was returned. [Here is the link to my query](https://pastebin.com/MPb22quB) Any thoughts?

Comment: @Leif I updated my answer using your sample data. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Works! Thank you for taking the time to help. Much appreciated.